# Lenovo laptop boot stuck on regulatory information screen

Tags: windows-10, bios, battery, lenovo-laptop

I used my laptop from this morning then suddenly my laptop died. When I turn on my laptop, a screen appears like this

[image: Lenovo Regulatory Information screen]

There is a command to press the enter key there but when the laptop is on, I come back to that screen again.

I found this article https://support.lenovo.com/ec/en/solutions/ht117630. I thought the method in this article will solve my problem but apparently I can't enter my laptop BIOS.

update 1 : ===================================

> "I can't enter my laptop BIOS"?

I've been able to get into the BIOS. It seems that the F2 key on my laptop is broken (maybe dust), I can enter the BIOS with an external keyboard.

Since I can enter the BIOS, I tried the method in the article I found. By going to the boot menu and changing the Boot Mode from UEFI to Legacy support, then save and exit. But I still returned to the Regulatory Information screen.

> "Can you boot from a CD/DVD or USB flash drive?"

I have a flash drive but at the moment around there's no other computer I can use so I can't try it.

Comment: What exactly means "I can't enter my laptop BIOS"? Don't you know how to do this? Do you get an error message? Please [edit] your question to add this information. Can you boot from a CD/DVD or USB flash drive?

Comment: @Bodo I have updated the question

Comment: When you enter the BIOS, can you see the hard disk device there? I suggest to create a flash drive or CD/DVD with a Linux rescue system, boot from it and check what's on the disk. Booting a Windows installation media and trying the repair options might also help.

Comment: I'll do it tomorrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened to me too. I suspect the reason why is because I put the laptop on sleep mode and forget about it till it ran out of battery.

I managed to get it working and here are the steps that I did:

1. Turn on your laptop and leave it be for a few minutes
2. Hold SHIFT and press the power button to turn off the laptop
3. Turn it back on and immediately hold fn while pressing F2 repeatedly

I managed to get my laptop back on without going to BIOS.
Hope this helps, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working as IT support and a customer had the same issue today with a Lenovo T14. The issue was caused by the USB dongle for wireless mouse & keyboard. It boot normally after removal.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just discovered, system booted properly after disconnecting keypad cable from planner(mbd) end.

Regards,

RM

Answer (score 0):

This happens consistently when my laptop (Thinkpad X13) is booted while connected to my Lenovo Thunderbolt-3 docking station. Disconnecting from the docking station while booting solves the issue. I suppose this is similar to the answers by @iustin-gabriel and @r-m.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) as well as other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also a site [tour] and  a [help].

Comment: Thank you for your additional information, may it help me in the future come